# Create a DIV container dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two lines of html code that already output by php

```
<div class="product-info weight">Weight: 10 kg</div>
<div class="product-info dimensions">Dimensions: 10 cm × 10 cm × 10 cm</div>
```

And i want to insert a div as a container to above two line so i can add some css to the container.

```
<div class="product-info-container">
    <div class="product-info weight">Weight: 10 kg</div>
    <div class="product-info dimensions">Dimensions: 10 cm × 10 cm × 10 cm</div>
</div>
```

is it possible to achieve by jquery? And how to do that?

Comment: You could use `wrap()` method of jquery.

Comment: @RobertHarvey it is not actually a duplicate... this is about wrapping an element with a new container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.wrapAll()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/)

```
$('.product-info').wrapAll('<div class="product-info-container"></div>')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qW36d/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".product-info.weight, .product-info.dimensions").wrapAll( "<div class='product-info-container'></div>" );
```